# Subscribe to Outlook/Office 365 API Status Code NotFound in C#

Tags: c#, office365, subscription, outlook-restapi

I am getting an issue when creating subscription.
My steps are:

1. Register app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
2. Update permissions
   Read Mail and User's info
3. Then update code, do same steps at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial
4. After login, I can get access token
   Screen after login
5. Then I try to create a subscription for Inbox

   ```
   var newSub = new Subscription
   {
       Resource = "me/mailFolders{'Inbox'}/messages",
       ChangeType = "created,updated",
       NotificationUrl = notificationUrl,
       ClientState = clientState,
       ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15)
   };
   var result = await graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(newSub);
   ```
6. Implement for notification in notification URL - I can get validation token and return in plain text.

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()
   {
       if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)
       {
           var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
           return Content(token, "plain/text");
       }
   }
   ```
7. But I always get this error.

[image: image description here]

Is there anyone know problem?

Comment: As per your provided steps, I tried new Subscription with my token in test project. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your issue since the post description "You must expose a public HTTPS endpoint to create a subscription and receive notifications from Microsoft Graph. " So your URL is correct or change the URL to test it? Post :https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample

Comment: Thank you Simon Li. I am using HTTP endpoint. I tried to change to HTTPS endpoint and it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must expose a public HTTPS endpoint to create a subscription and receive notifications from Microsoft Graph.